# CSS debug is not the same before and after rendering

Tags: css, debugging

i got a website here that i am building up [HERE](http://studioteknik.co/solertia.ca/en/)

the right arrow, in chrome, is LOW as you can see [here](http://studioteknik.co/solertia.ca/bug.jpg)

but when i debug it with the debugger and check float on/off, it comeback to the place it should be...

so the question is, what is the problem ? the CSS, the browser, the debugger the system (mac?) or HTML... if need your light !... thanks in advance

Comment: please post sample code  - not a link to your personal site - that can be considered spam

Comment: when you are editing a page in the developer tools are you are really doing is getting a preview of what the page would look like if that css property was gone.  These changes are not permenatly saved , it is just a preview - then you go into your css on our server and make those changes that you previewed

Comment: you what me to post the whole HTML page and all the CSS files here... NOPE it wont append, I got the link to the buggy page, everybody can load it... no spam, ni virus, just a plain simple WP site being build...

Comment: why you remove my links ?... it does not make sens without link... WTF ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I explained why I removed the links

Comment: i belive stackoverflow was (where?) a place to get help from people... i NEVER get treaten like that with a question i got here.... what append to Stackoverflow ?

Comment: ok - sorry , didn't mean to be rude , I was just saying it's best to show an example of the problem as best you can through code of images or an expplanation without linking to your own site , anyways , I will answer it to make up for the fact that I was rude I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's not really intuitive, however, try one of two following, both of which will fix it for you:

Add `float:left` to .bx-wrapper, which then makes all the elements floating.

OR

move the "fg" div before the bx-wrapper div.

Comment: There are other things that can and would have cause the arrow to pop back up as well.  Some transitions or animations might have triggered it as well.  Sometimes it's a mouse click on a different element will cause it as well.  I've seen this issue before, and it is definitely a chrome only issue, but either of the two above fixes should remedy the problem.  Mixing floating and non-floating elements, some of which are inline-block, and trying to make the last element float:right... bad in chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote with no explanation as to why.  Both of these circumvent the bug in chrome. If you don't like the answer, please post a better one.

Comment: Still not sure why this keeps getting down voted when both of these fix the original problem and no other answers that work are given.

Answer (score 1):

you need to clear the float

try adding

```
float: clear;
```

what is happening when you uncheck and then check is it is getting cleared out on it's own

or....

don't use floats and you can see why make them all

```
display: inline-block;
```

i'm going to get negative comments about that one, but seriously it's so much easier and more dependable .  If the items that are all `inline-block` fit in the row then they will stay in the row

Comment: and if i clear the value can only be : left
right
both
none
inherit... and it does not fix the problem.... arrow must be at the right... i try to find what push it down

Comment: clear:both, make it WORST... it down all the time... did you get it at your screen BEFORE posting... the arrow MUST be right aling to the other arrow... now low like now....

Comment: It must be a google chrome rendering engine bug... let trash chrome, and all use firefox or IE, or make it require to get the site right (NO,  it's a joke !)

Comment: These answers don't work.  clear:both will cause the arrow to consistently drop, and using inline-block won't allow for a responsive design.

Comment: why would you think that inline-block will not allow responsive design?

Comment: Please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/1nohtrur/  Without knowing the width of the containing div (as it may vary), you can't give the middle div a correct width without using either javascript or using css3 styles (using calc) that aren't available to all browsers, assuming the left and right blocks are of fixed widths.